# Coudn't pass the form values one page to another asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have to values values one form to another using asp.net i can pass to another only regno and name only another values cannot pass i got the error missing directive what i tried so far i attached below

```
<div class="row">
                       <div class="col-sm-4">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Reg No</label>    
                          <asp:TextBox ID="regno" runat="server"  class="form-control" required></asp:TextBox>
                       </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Name</label>
                           <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"  class="form-control" required></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Address</label>
                               <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Gender</label>
                              <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" Text="Male" />
                              <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="FeMale" />
                           </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Interest</label>
                                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Cricket" />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Football" />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="Cinima" />
                           </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />
                           </div>



                       </div>
```

**Button Event**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("form2.aspx?regno=" +
            this.regno.Text + "&name=" +
            this.name.Text  + "&phone=" + 
            this.phone.Text ); this line i got error missing directive


        }
```

**Second form**

```
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["regno"];
             Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];
             Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["phone"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phone seems to be ordinary input and not TextBox (note the input tag and lowercase id). Also, you are requesting a txtphone while id=phone.

Be aware, string data should be Url encoded before sending it through querystring.

Edit: replace

```
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required />
```

with

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="phone" runat="server"  class="form-control" required></asp:TextBox>
```

Edit: for checkboxes, use something like

```
var interests = new List<string>();
if (chkCheckBox1.Checked)
    interests.Add(chkCheckBox1.Text);
if (chkCheckBox2.Checked)
    interests.Add(chkCheckBox2.Text);
if (chkCheckBox3.Checked)
    interests.Add(chkCheckBox3.Text);
var interestsString = string.Join(",", interests);

var sex = RadioButton1.Checked ? RadioButton1.Text : RadioButton1.Text;

Response.Redirect("form2.aspx" +
    "?regno=" + this.regno.Text + 
    "&name=" + this.name.Text + 
    "&phone=" + this.phone.Text +
    "&sex=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sex) + 
    "&interest=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(interestsString) +


// if needed, decode with HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["interest"]:
// var interests = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(interestsString);
```

Comment: i changed the phone no  this.phone.Text );  this still error

Comment: thank you sir and RadioButton and checkbox  select data how to pass sir

Comment: what does your RadioButton1_CheckedChanged says?

Comment: I have added text but you have RadioButton1_CheckedChanged event which handles values. You are missing GroupName="sex" attribute on both radio buttons which makes sure you can click only one option.